# Adding objects from business layer to crystal report (c#.net)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I made a crystal report using c#.net, we can add only the objects that exist on the project that contains crystal report, is there any way to add .net objects from my business layer to my report and how?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your query ?

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/558_How_to_Generate_Crystal_Report_Using_Custom_Object_Collection_with_ASP_NET.aspx